# Default test case in Postman

Tags: postman

I have recently started using postman for API automation. But I am seeing a default test case getting added to postman even I have not mentioned any test case explicitly. Whenever API Request is successful, it shows "**PASS** : No Errors in response" in Test results. But I did not have any test case in tests section.

So could you please help me to understand where it is coming from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this collection from someone? It might have a test set at the collection level. Without seeing more information about what you're seeing, it's hard to tell. Can you share a screen shot?

Comment: Hi Danny Dainton, I only created this collection. As you can see in screenshot "PASS: No Errors in response" test case is not available either at request/collection/environment level but seeing it in results.

Comment: I can't see a screenshot :)

Comment: Hi Danny Dainton, Please ignore this request, Issue resolved the test case was triggered from Collection. So I just removed it from Collection level.

Comment: So basically, what I said it might be. :)